# How to traceroute with Indy10 TIdIcmpClient?

Tags: c++builder, indy10, icmp, traceroute, c++builder-xe5

To do a trace route we can read in the Indy [documentation](http://www.indyproject.org/docsite/html/frames.html?frmname=topic&frmfile=index.html)

> "For Traceroute application, send ping echo requests with increased
>   TTL values"

The problem is that the TTL property is protected and can't be set. Is this just another bug or do I really have to define a new class to make the TTL property public?

However, I did a new class (including the Ping work around):

```
class TPing : public TIdIcmpClient {

  public:
    __property TTL;

    __fastcall TPing(TComponent* Owner) : TIdIcmpClient(Owner) {};
    __fastcall Ping(unsigned int Id = 0) {
      AnsiString Proxy = StringOfChar('X',PacketSize);
      TIdIcmpClient::Ping(Proxy,Id);
    }

};
```

If I set TTL to 5 and call Ping to google.com (I have checked that there is 6 TTL to google.com from my location).

So a TTL of 5 will generate an ICMP timeout message and according to the documentation, the last IP will be returned. But instead I get IP `0.0.0.0`. This is the member values of `AReplyStatus` in the `OnReply(TComponent *ASender, const TReplyStatus *AReplyStatus)` callback.

```
FByteReceived    0,
FFromIpAddress   { u"0.0.0.0" },
FToIpAddress     { u"0.0.0.0" },
FMsgType         '\0',
FMsgCode         '\0',
FSequenceId      3490U(0x0DA2),
FMsRoundTripTime 109,
FTimeToLive      '\0',
FReplyStatus     2 /* rsTimeOut */,
FPacketNumber    0,
FHostName        { NULL },
FMsg             { NULL },
FRedirectTo      { NULL }
```

If I change the TTL to 6 everything works as expected (google.com answers) and I get rsEcho in return.

**So to clarify the question:**
How can I do a traceroute (Incrementing TTL) to collect all the router IP addresses along the way?

Comment: Indy has a separate `TIdTraceRoute` component.

Comment: Yes, I found it but it isn't working. For each TTL timeout, Indy isn't returning until its own timeout has been reached, not when the ICMP returns the timeout datagram (I have checked this with WireShark). When Indy finally returns and call OnReply...

Comment: ...(continue) AReplyStatus isn't initialized correctly. Source address is 0.0.0.0 not the last trace IP. I get the same result as above with TraceRoute as well. TraaceRoute is also experiencing the TIdIcmpClient problem with random error #10040 (and this would be logic if there is a bug in TIdIcmpClient).

Comment: If there is a timeout datagram being sent, it is either not being delivered to Indy by the OS at all, or its Sequence number is not what Indy is expecting. Otherwise, Indy has no reason to wait for its own timeout to elapse before returning back to you. It returns as soon as it has data to return. A Source address of 0.0.0.0 means Indy did not receive any data to decode.

Comment: Yes, and this is why it is so strange. If I use the TraceRoute class, I can see in WireShark how Indy is sending from TTL 1 to TTL 6 where google answer. But for each ICMP Time-To-Live exceeded reply from each router, Indy isn't reacting, waiting for the internal timeout before sending the next TTL level. As soon Google responds, Indy returns as expected but displays now so famous "Error #10040 Message to long". The id numbers are identical for sending and replying. I don't see why the underlying IP level would block just some ICMP messages?

Comment: Did you try debugging into Indy's code to make sure the OS is actually delivering the packets to `TIdTraceRoute`? Just because Wireshark shows it does not mean the OS is delivering it. Wireshark operates on a completely different layer than apps operate on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done some poking around and managed to do a trace with the Win32 API instead of Indy.
The Win32 API is quite straight forward and has a function for just ICMP Echo: [IcmpSendEcho](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366050%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

You need to use the optional RequestOptions to set the TTL from 1 and increase for each call until you either reach your hop limit or get a success back.

The Indy component just doesn't seem to return on errors, only on a success or timeout (ms not TTL).

I have boiled down my code to a minimum (not tested although).

```
IP_OPTION_INFORMATION Options;

IPAddr           Host;   // Host address to ping
char             SendData[32] = "Echo";
HANDLE           hIcmp;
LPVOID           ReplyBuffer;
DWORD            ReplySize;
PICMP_ECHO_REPLY pEchoReply;
int              TTL = 0;
int              Timeout = 5000; // 5 seconds timeout
bool             done = false;

// Prepare ICMP operation
Host = inet_addr("74.125.232.95"); // Google server
hIcmp = IcmpCreateFile();

if (hIcmp == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
  return psICMPFailure;
}

// Prepare ISMP reply buffer
ReplySize   = sizeof(ICMP_ECHO_REPLY) + 32;
ReplyBuffer = (VOID*) malloc(ReplySize);

while (!done && TTL++<30) {

  // Prepare options
  Options.Ttl = TTL;
  Options.Tos = 0;
  Options.Flags = IP_FLAG_DF;
  Options.OptionsSize = 0;
  Options.OptionsData = NULL;

  // PING
  IcmpSendEcho(hIcmp,Host,SendData,sizeof(SendData),&Options,ReplyBuffer,ReplySize, Timeout);

  // get result
  pEchoReply = (PICMP_ECHO_REPLY)ReplyBuffer;

  // Do something like adding the Host IP to a list

  // Check ICMP status
  done = (pEchoReply->Status == 0);
}

// Cleanup
IcmpCloseHandle(hIcmp);
free(ReplyBuffer);
```